# jQuery replacement for nested getElementsByTagName

Tags: jquery, nested, getelementsbytagname

I want to use jQuery for nested getElementsByTagName. Many questions deal with nested each, but they veer off into special topics. I can't figure out something that is probably very simple. In pure JavaScript I have:

```
tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
for (var t = 0; t < tables.length; t++)
{
    thisTable = tables[t];
    if (thisTable.id == "specialID")
    {
        inputs = thisTable.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var r=0; r < inputs.length; r++)
        {
            thisInput = inputs[r];
            if (thisInput.type == "radio")
            {
                if (thisInput.checked == true)
                {
                    [do stuff]
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically this does some testing on certain radio buttons inside of a desired table. The syntax of the nested getElementByTagName is what is causing me problems when I try to convert to jQuery. So far I have this:

```
$("table").each(function () {
    if (this.id == "specialID")
    {
        $("this:input").each(function () {
            alert("I am here");
            [test for radio and do stuff]
        });
    }
});
```

The first "each" on tables is working fine and finds all the tables. But the second "each" on inputs doesn't select any of the input controls inside a particular table. I suspect the $("this.input") is incorrect, but I have tried many other things here and I get syntax errors or no better results. What is the right way to form the syntax that lets me iterate over all the inputs inside one of all the tables?

Comment: Try `$(this).find("input")` instead of `$("this:input")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can only have **one** table with the `id` `"specialID"`, you can do this:

```
$("#specialId input").each(function () {
    // ...do stuff with the input
});
```

However, in the *general* case where you might have more than one outer element and want to handle things on inner elements for only some of them:

```
$("selector-for-outer-element").each(function () {
    if (/*...some condition...*/) {
        $(this).find("selector-for-inner-elements").each(function() {
            // ...do something with the inner elements
        });
    }
});
```

Or if the condition can be expressed as a selector, naturally apply the condition that way instead:

```
$("selector-for-outer-element.some-condition selector-for-inner-elements").each(function () {
    // ...do something with the inner elements
});
```

...which is basically what I did with the very first snippet above.

Comment: Thank you, TJCrowder. I am trying to apply your first suggestion but have run into a problem. While my original post gave a simplified "specialID" I was trying to shield a detail, which is that I am actually checking tables with an ID that CONTAINS "specialID". So I don't actually have the ID. However, I do have this.ID, so instead of your $("#specialId input").each(function () I used $("#this.id input").each(function (). That doesn't work ;-(. Isn't there a way to use "this" or "$this" in the selector in some way, with the caveat that what I really want is the inputs from the "this"? Thanks.

Comment: @user3487095: Yes, via string concatenation: `$("#" + this.id + " input").each(...` But if `this` is the element that has the `input`s in it, you can use this instead: `$(this).find("input").each(...`

Comment: OK, I discovered how to use the this in the selector. $($(this)).each works, or I can assign a local tab=$(this) and simply use $(tab).each. But how do I get the inputs? I tried $(tab:input), $(tab input) and $(tab.input) but none work.

Comment: @user3487095: See above, my previous comment says exactly how to get the `input` elements. Also, note that ` $($(this)).each` is just a long way to write `$(this).each`.

Comment: Sorry, T.J.Crowder, I didn't see your last comment before I made that last post. I haven't studied what you wrote, but I DID figure out that I ought to be able to duplicate what you had as your very first suggestion by doing tab = $(this); and tabid = this.id. So $("#tabid input").each(... should work. But it doesn't ;-(  Isn't this what you had? Are you sure the ID<space>ELEMENT syntax works??

Comment: You're right, of course. $this works like $($(this)). But I still like your this<space>element-name syntax to pull out the inputs, instead of using "find". Can that work somehow with "this" ?? That is my main question for all of this -- a simple way to use jQuery syntax to select an element (input) after getting an element identified by "this".

Comment: I accepted your answer and thank you for the dialog. I'll admit the find syntax in the inner loop is not so terrible and it works(!) But I still think the <space> elementname is tighter -- although I had an indication it doesn't work. If you're sure that works, why do I have to use "find" in the inner nest?

Comment: @user3487095: The space in `$("one two")` is a *descendant combinator*: It means "match all `two`s that are anywhere inside `one`s". So for instance, `$(".foo div")` matches all `div` elements anywhere inside any elements with class `foo`. In your case, if `this` is an element and you want to look inside it, while you *could* use `this.id` if it has one (`$("#" + this.id + " input")`) to match all `input` elements anywhere inside the element with that `id`, you're probably better off with `$(this).find("input")`, which finds all elements within the element you have in `this`.